# Longer stack traces in Julia

Tags: stack-trace, julia

I'm trying to catch an elusive error in my Julia code, but it's not giving me enough of a stack trace to catch it. I'm used to using Chrome's tools for JavaScript and being able to get the full stack trace. How can I print the entire path taken through my Julia code so I can catch the bug?

I've tried using the `backtrace` function, but I don't know how to decipher the pointers I seem to be getting back from it.

`[Ptr{Void} @0x000000010cbc6416,Ptr{Void} @0x000000010cb788ab...]`

Answer (score 1):

Typically errors do give full stacktraces; if not, you've encountered a bug. What kind of error are you getting? What platform are you on?

If you have a backtrace, you can show it like this: `Base.show_backtrace(STDOUT, bt)`.